# Setting an element to fixed position when scrolling makes that element blink

Tags: jquery, html, css, sticky

I am using a jQuery plugin called stickyjs (http://stickyjs.com/) to make an element stick to the top of the browser when it reaches the top. It works perfectly fine on my Mac.. but when I use the mouse scroll wheel on my PC it blinks once really fast as soon as the element reaches the top of the page. If I drag the scrollbar it does not blink. It only happens when I use the scroll wheel.. weird!!! You should be able to see it happen on stickyjs's demo page: http://stickyjs.com/

You can see the white "Sticky" header blinks and so do the buttons that say "Download Plugin" and "Fork on Github." Again, this seems to only be happening on PC's.

Does anyone know what is causing this? Is there a way around it?

Comment: On FireFox I see nothing blinking.

Comment: Ok, I tested on Chrome and IE on the PC (Win 8).

Comment: Might I recommend **[waypoints.js](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/)** ?

Answer (score 0):

Set `position:fixed` from the start. The problem seems to be that the position is assigned after you scrolled. So basically you scroll, the div gets left behind and then the position is added making it go back at the top of the window. That will make it blink

Comment: But doesn't that defeat the whole purpose of the plugin? Say I have an element that is 500px from the top of the page. I want that element to scroll along with everything else *until* it hits the top of the browser window, then it becomes fixed and sticks in place while everything else scrolls under it.